# Why am I getting a value error from my while loop?

Tags: python, while-loop

I don't understand why I'm getting a Value Error. I specifically exclude the "*" character.....yet it still gets included and causes an error. I understand I have to figure out how to reverse the output too but I'll worry about that later.

> Write a program that reads a list of integers, one per line, until an
> "*" is read, then outputs those integers in reverse. For simplicity in coding output, follow each integer, including the last one, by a
> comma.
>
> Note: Use a while loop to output the integers. DO NOT use reverse() or
> reversed().
>
> Ex: If the input is:

```
2
4
6
8
10
*
```

> the output is:

```
10,8,6,4,2,
```

my code:

```
''' Type your code here. '''
while True:
    try:
        if input().strip() != "*":
            num = input().strip()
            lst = []
            lst.append(num)
            print("{},".format(int(num),end=""))
        else:
            break
    except EOFError:
        break
```

> Enter program input (optional)

```
2
4
6
8
10
*
```

> Program errors displayed here

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
    print("{},".format(int(num),end=""))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '*'
```

> Program output displayed here

```
4,
8,
```

Comment: Why are you taking two input one in while loop condition and other inside while loop ?

Comment: `num` is being created _after_ your `if` statement, so it's allowed to be '*' by your code.

Comment: Your first call to `input()` takes the first number and throws it away. Your second call to `input()` actually processes what the user types. So each time throughthe loop eats *two* input numbers. In that last pair, your code tests if `10` is equal to `"*"`, then it inputs `*` and attempts to convert that to an integer, which fails

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're using input 2 times:

- First input read 10 and it passes the if.
- Second input read "*" inside the "action" section of your code and fails.

Also:

- You're resetting the list on every loop. The initialization should be outside of the loop.
- Using a more pythonic way to check if the `"*"` is in the data should avoid any further issues, for example, using `"**"` or having an incorrect input `"1*"`.

An updated version of the code will be:

```py
''' Type your code here. '''
lst = []
while True:
    try:
        data = input().strip()
        if "*" not in data:
            lst.append(num)
            print("{},".format(int(num),end=""))
        else:
            break
    except EOFError:
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`append`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) to add numbers to the list `lst`, and [`pop`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) to remove them from the end of the list. Use [f-strings or formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) to print the list elements.

```
num = input().strip()
lst = []

while num != '*':
    num = int(num)
    lst.append(num)
    num = input().strip()

while lst:
    num = lst.pop()
    print(f"{num},", end='')
print('')
```

---

Comments on your code:

```
while True:
    try: # No need for the try block.
        if input().strip() != "*": # This input gets lost: not assigned to any variable.
            num = input().strip() # This input is not tested whether it is '*'.
            lst = [] # This list gets assigned anew ands becomes empty with every iteration.
            lst.append(num)
            print("{},".format(int(num),end="")) # Use f-strings instead (easier).
        else:
            break
    except EOFError:
        break
```